# MYSQL - Export data into outfile with pivot-table query

Tags: mysql, into-outfile, select-into-outfile

I wrote a script that gather the space used by multiple datasets.

My database looks like the below:

| Date_and_Time | Server_Name_and_Drive | Space_Used_(Gb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08/04 00:00 | SERVER3 D DRIVE | 220 |
| 08/04 00:00 | SERVER2 D DRIVE | 10 |
| 08/04 00:00 | SERVER1 D DRIVE | 64 |
| 08/04 12:00 | SERVER3 D DRIVE | 221 |
| 08/04 12:00 | SERVER2 D DRIVE | 10 |
| 08/04 12:00 | SERVER1 D DRIVE | 67 |
| 09/04 00:00 | SERVER3 D DRIVE | 223 |
| 09/04 00:00 | SERVER2 D DRIVE | 11 |
| 09/04 00:00 | SERVER1 D DRIVE | 73 |
| 09/04 12:00 | SERVER3 D DRIVE | 225 |
| 09/04 12:00 | SERVER2 D DRIVE | 12 |
| 09/04 12:00 | SERVER1 D DRIVE | 75 |

Now, I want to get the data from my database. I am using the below to get a CSV out of it:

> select * from myTable where Server_Name_and_Drive like "%DRIVE%" into outfile '/var/lib/mysql/myTable_date.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

This gives me the below output csv file:

> 08/04 00:00,SERVER3 D DRIVE,220
> 08/04 00:00,SERVER2 D DRIVE,10
> 08/04 00:00,SERVER1 D DRIVE,64
> 08/04 12:00,SERVER3 D DRIVE,221
> 08/04 12:00,SERVER2 D DRIVE,10
> 08/04 12:00,SERVER1 D DRIVE,67
> 09/04 00:00,SERVER3 D DRIVE,223
> 09/04 00:00,SERVER2 D DRIVE,11
> 09/04 00:00,SERVER1 D DRIVE,73
> 09/04 12:00,SERVER3 D DRIVE,225
> 09/04 12:00,SERVER2 D DRIVE,12
> 09/04 12:00,SERVER1 D DRIVE,75

Now, I would like to get the output differently and group the Date_and_Time, having only one line per same Date_and_Time, and the repeated row into column, such as below:

> Date_and_Time,SERVER1 D DRIVE(Gb),SERVER2 D DRIVE(Gb),SERVER3 D DRIVE(Gb)
> 08/04 00:00,220,10,64
> 08/04 12:00,221,10,67
> 09/04 00:00,223,11,73
> 09/04 12:00,225,12,75

Is this possible using the "select" and "into outfile" to export it as CSV from the database?

Obviously, my table is much bigger and gather lots of different data, I simplify it this way to focus on the output I want.

Please, be kind as it is my first post here on stackoverflow.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards, Nick

---

I tried to use pivot table on mysql but cannot make it to work.

database example:

| Date_Time | Server_drive | areaUsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-08 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER01/DRIVES/G | 106953154560 |
| 2022-04-08 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER02/DRIVES/F | 717575577600 |
| 2022-04-08 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER03/DRIVES/D | 159979786240 |
| 2022-04-08 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER04/DRIVES/W | 25792897024 |
| 2022-04-08 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER01/DRIVES/G | 106953154560 |
| 2022-04-08 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER02/DRIVES/F | 717718970368 |
| 2022-04-08 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER03/DRIVES/D | 159979786240 |
| 2022-04-08 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER04/DRIVES/W | 25792897024 |
| 2022-04-09 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER01/DRIVES/G | 106953154560 |
| 2022-04-09 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER02/DRIVES/F | 717718970368 |
| 2022-04-09 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER03/DRIVES/D | 159981051904 |
| 2022-04-09 00:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER04/DRIVES/W | 25792897024 |
| 2022-04-09 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER01/DRIVES/G | 106953154560 |
| 2022-04-09 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER02/DRIVES/F | 717874745344 |
| 2022-04-09 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER03/DRIVES/D | 159977820160 |
| 2022-04-09 12:00:02 | /private_shares/SERVER04/DRIVES/W | 25792897024 |

I tried the following query but cannot make it to work:

> SELECT areaUsage.Date_Time,
> MAX(CASE WHEN areaUsage.Server_drive like "%SERVER01/DRIVES/G%" THEN areaUsage.areaUsed END) "SERVER01 DRIVE G",
> MAX(CASE WHEN areaUsage.Server_drive like "%SERVER02/DRIVES/F%" THEN areaUsage.areaUsed END) "SERVER02 DRIVE F",
> MAX(CASE WHEN areaUsage.Server_drive like "%SERVER03/DRIVES/D%" THEN areaUsage.areaUsed END) "SERVER03 DRIVE D",
> MAX(CASE WHEN areaUsage.Server_drive like "%SERVER04/DRIVES/W%" THEN areaUsage.areaUsed END) "SERVER04 DRIVE W",
> FROM areaUsage
> GROUP BY areaUsage.Date_Time
> ORDER BY areaUsage.Date_Time ASC;

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The error output is as below:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM areaUsage GROUP BY areaUsage.currentTime' at line 1

Comment: Yes, you can use `INTO OUTFILE` with any `SELECT` query. It seems like you want a [tag:pivot-table] query. There are lots of examples. Here's a link to one of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721650/mysql-dynamic-rows-to-columns/43721751#43721751

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, I will have a look at your post.

Comment: I edited my post to include what I have tried so far but encounter error 1064, can you guide me in resolving my query issue please @BillKarwin ?

Comment: Just remove the last comma before the from statement

Comment: Thanks @Thallius this was my issues, I managed also to reformat the Date_Time using the below:

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(areaUsage.currentTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS niceDate