# Replacement rows with columns using MySQL 8.0.12

Tags: mysql, left-join, pivot-table

This query with `left join` syntax, relates two tables, the table `tbl_t` and the table `tbl_p`

```
SELECT
    tProgr,
    tLevel,
    pProg_related,
    pLevel 
FROM
    tbl_t t
    LEFT JOIN tbl_p p ON t.tProgr = p.tProgr 
WHERE
    t.tProgr = '2022-0071' 
ORDER BY
    t.tProgr DESC;
```

The return

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| tProgr    | tLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2022-0071 | Principal  | 2022-0010     | Secondary  |
| 2022-0071 | Principal  | 2022-0065     | Secondary  |
| 2022-0071 | Principal  | 2022-0076     | Secondary  |
| 2022-0071 | Principal  | 2022-0182     | Secondary  |
| 2022-0071 | Principal  | 2022-0223     | Secondary  |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I get this return instead?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tProgr    | tLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2022-0071 | Principal  | 2022-0010     | Secondary  | 2022-0065     | Secondary  | 2022-0076     | Secondary  | 2022-0182     | Secondary  | 2022-0223     | Secondary  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help really appreciated.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tProgr    | tLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     | pProg_related | pLevel     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2022-0071 | Principal  | 2022-0010     | Secondary  | 2022-0065     | Secondary  | 2022-0076     | Secondary  | 2022-0182     | Secondary  | 2022-0223     | Secondary  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There are many solutions posted, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594902/row-to-column-transformation-in-mysql/25594969#25594969 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721650/mysql-dynamic-rows-to-columns/43721751#43721751 or

Comment: See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired output where the related records are shown in separate columns, you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function along with the GROUP BY clause. Here is an example query that should give the desired output:

```
SELECT 
    tProgr, 
    tLevel, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(pProg_related SEPARATOR ', ') AS pProg_related, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(pLevel SEPARATOR ', ') AS pLevel
FROM 
    tbl_t t
    LEFT JOIN tbl_p p ON t.tID = p.tID 
WHERE 
    t.tProgr = '2022-0071' 
GROUP BY 
    t.tProgr, 
    t.tLevel 
ORDER BY 
    t.tProgr DESC;
```

In this query, we are using the GROUP_CONCAT function to concatenate the related records separated by a comma for each group of tProgr and tLevel. The GROUP BY clause is used to group the results by the tProgr and tLevel columns.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() concatenates column values and does not show them in separate columns.